# Struggle with resetting coroutine

Tags: unity, c#

A little bit of context; I'm still not experienced at this, I'm creating a 2D platformer and this is my enemies script (some part of it). This is supposed to be a minatour, which charges towards the player on sight. When rays hit the player I call the Charge coroutine from update. As you can see below rays are not casted during the coroutine. Everything works according to plan, but after this coroutine ends if rays hit the player in two seconds, coroutine never stops again, rays are always casted and the minatour always keep charging. But if rays hit the player after 2 seconds it's perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (!canChargeRight && !canChargeLeft)
    {
        rightRay = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right, rayDistance, layerMask);
        leftRay = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.left, rayDistance, layerMask);

        if (rightRay.collider != null)
        {
            canChargeLeft = true;
        }
        else if (leftRay.collider != null)
        {
            canChargeRight = true;
        }
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (canChargeRight)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Charge(-1));
    } else if (canChargeLeft)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Charge(1));
    }
}

private IEnumerator Charge(int chargeDirection)
{
    myRigidBody.velocity = Vector2.right * chargeDirection * chargeSpeed;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    canChargeLeft = false;
    canChargeRight = false;
    myRigidBody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to post this as a comment, but it seems I need 50 reputation for that. Are you calling `StopCoroutine` anywhere? If `canChargeRight` and `canChargeLeft` are successfully being set to `false` as intended, I would imagine that you would want to call `StopCoroutine` in your `Update` function if those variables are `false`. ----------
I found this on Unity's forum, which may be of use to you: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-cancel-and-restart-a-coroutine.435493/

Comment: It looks like you're starting a copy of this coroutine every frame, as long as canChargeRight or canChargeLeft remain true. That doesn't look like what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DMGregory mentioned, I guess the main issue was calling the coroutine in update function. Here is the final version if anyone is interested

```
 void Update()
{
    if(!chargingLeft && !chargingRight)
    {
        if ((player.position.x - transform.position.x) < 0)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(1, 1);           //this is where we flip enemy 
        }
        else
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1, 1);
        }
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (canCharge)
    {
        rightRay = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right, rayDistance, layerMask);
        leftRay = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.left, rayDistance, layerMask);

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, rayDistance * Vector2.right, Color.green);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, rayDistance * Vector2.left, Color.red);

        if (rightRay.collider != null)
        {
            chargingRight = true;
            StartCoroutine(Charge());
            canCharge = false;
        }
        else if (leftRay.collider != null)
        {
            chargingLeft = true;
            StartCoroutine(Charge());
            canCharge = false;
        }
    }

    if (chargingLeft)
    {
        myRigidBody.velocity = Vector2.left * chargeSpeed;
    } else if (chargingRight)
    {
        myRigidBody.velocity = Vector2.right * chargeSpeed;
    }
}

private IEnumerator Charge()
{
    myAnimator.SetBool("Charge", true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    myAnimator.SetBool("Charge", false);
    myRigidBody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    chargingRight = false;
    chargingLeft = false;
    StartCoroutine(Recovery());
}

private IEnumerator Recovery()
{
    StopCoroutine(charge);
    //recovery
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    canCharge = true;
}
```

Comment: If this is the solution to your issue, you might want to mark it as accepted :)